# Model a 5-Bar Manipulator with Armatures

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I'd like to model a [5-bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-bar_linkage) manipulator with armatures which should work like this:

[image]

For my understanding this would imply two bone tails which are connected to each others (at the connection to the red bar).
As far as I know this is not possible.

Do you have any idea how to assemble this mechanism?